# Can't find symbol (method) which is defined in an object's class

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, getter

This here is the code for a class that modelizes a catalog for a computer parts shop using an ArrayList. All the included objects (products) have been defined, including methods for getting and setting a quantity variable.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AvailablesCatalog {

public AvailablesCatalog(List cat1) {

    Motherboard item1 = new Motherboard("MD4652", 1995, "Lenovo", 100.50,  "Intel", 32, 5, 0);
    CPU item2 = new CPU("RTJ357", 1850, "Intel", 182.50, 2.9, 6, 0);
    Graphics item3 = new Graphics("P99E0", 2014, "AMD", 70.50, "AMD", 6, 0);
    RAM item4 = new RAM("THN46", 1999, "Microsoft", 30.50, "DDR2", 4, 1600, 0);
    HD item5 = new HD("M9052", 2001, "LG", 100, "SSD", 2.5, 750, 0);
    Monitor item6 = new Monitor("D42", 2006, "LG", 200, "LED", 17.5, "1920x1080", "HDMI", 0);
    Keyboard item7 = new Keyboard("F16", 2010, "Microsoft", 25.70, "Wireless", 0);
    Mouse item8 = new Mouse("JERRY", 2010, "Microsoft", 30.50, "Laser", "Wireless", 0);
    Printer item9 = new Printer("PRNTR", 1995, "Lexmark", 40.50, "Laser", "Colored", 0);

    cat1.add(item1);    
    cat1.add(item2);   
    cat1.add(item3);   
    cat1.add(item4);
    cat1.add(item5);
    cat1.add(item6);   
    cat1.add(item7);   
    cat1.add(item8);
    cat1.add(item9);

}

public String toString(List cat1) {
    int flag = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<cat1.size(); i++) {
        if(cat1.get(i).getQuantity() != 0) {
            System.out.println(cat1.get(i).toString());
        }
        else {
            flag ++;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 9) {
        System.out.println("No products");
    }
    return "-------------------------------------------------------------------------";
}

}
```

As you can see, i'm trying to use the getQuantity() method in the AvailablesCatalog class. The problem is that when i try to compile i get a cannot find symbol error for the getQuantity method. Does that mean that i actually need to define the method in the catalog's class as well? In which case, how do i make it return each different product's quantity? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: since i didn't make that clear, all the product objects have a common Product superclass. Then, should i change
    toString(List cat1)

to

```
toString(List<Product> cat1)
```

?

EDIT 2: That was indeed the case after all, the only prblem was being that i was defining getQuantity() in all of my products, instead of the base class (Product) Once again, thanks  everyone.

Comment: You will want to update the parameter in the constructor too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using a genericized List, so when you call `get(i)` on it, it returns an `Object`, and there is no `getQuantity()` method on `Object`. Try declaring your `List` as a `List<Category>` or whatever your base class for `RAM`, `Motherboard`, `Keyboard` etc is.

Answer (score 3):

because compiler doesn't know that your objects in `List` would be of type `Catalog`

change

```
List cat1
```

to

```
List<Catalog> cat1
```

in `toString()`

Assumming `Catalog` is your class containing this method and you have strictly all objects of this type in list

Comment: You don't want a `List<AvailablesCatalog>` as that would be a list of catalogs. He wants a list of things that are *in* the catalog.

Comment: But then which type of object do i even begin to put in the <> ?

Comment: @user113377 you should have a base class from which `RAM`, `Motherboard`, `Keyboard` etc inherit (as I implied in my answer). If you're not doing it this way, you should strongly consider it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we do not understand what items you're adding to the list. What are the superclass of `Motherboard`, `Graphics`, `CPU`, `Monitor`, `Keyboard`, `Mouse`, etc.?

Since you're using a generic `List` without specifying a type, it is seen as a `raw type` and thus, the items in the list are implicitly an `Object` and `Object` doesn't have a `getQuantity()` method.

A solution will be to create an `Item` abstract, `Serialize`d class that all the relevant subclass must inherit, i.e., `Keyboard`, `Mouse`, `Motherboard`, etc., and a `List` of these `Items`, i.e., `List<Item> cat1`.

Then your `toString` will have the following method signature:

```
public String toString(List<? extends Item> cat1)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Product` as a generic wildcard argument

```
public String toString(List<? extends Product> categoryList) {
```